# Table partinioning (horizontal) with doctrine

Tags: mysql, database, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am using Doctrine 2.4 and I want to split the table one of my entity is using into several tables to improve querying that table - Horizontal partitioning, if I am not mistaken. The table has a lot of data (> 20 Mio. rows) and queries are always done on a subset (Component.Type).

Here are my entities:

Station:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

Component:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $type;
```

Data

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $datetime;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
 */
private $value;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Station")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="station_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 * @var Station $station
 */
private $station;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Component")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="component_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 * @var Component $component
 */
private $component;
```

At the moment I solved this manually by having one Entity Data[TYPE] for every Component.Type (e.g. `DataPollutionNo`). All entities Data[TYPE] extent a MappedSuperclass (Data). To query for data, I first get the corresponding Data Entity from the Component.Type and query that Repository (`DataPollutionNoRepository`). This works out fine but I was wondering if there is a more sophisticated/generic approach to solve this.

Thanks, Hannes